# make swosh fluid stylised motion graphics

Tags: geometry-nodes, fluid-simulation

is there a way to make such designs in blender? like fluid moving stylized mograph style. have been trying, not very good in blender.
Thanks

[image]

Comment: I believe there is, but it depends on how you want it done, i.e. how you want it to be flexible after making it.

Comment: could you explain one way to me pls. much appreciated

Comment: Well, the first thing I think of is a very blobby looking circular curve extruded along a large wave one, but the trick then is how to make the yellow areas. Maybe the blobby one has one long arm that forms the curtain… I’ll try it.

Comment: Missed that it was motion graphics. Can you provide an example where it is moving? I'm not familiar enough with this style.

Comment: Please be more specific about your problem or provide additional details to show exactly what you need. The way it's written now, it's hard to see exactly what you're asking for. Thank you!